# pywinauto does not detect child window

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

I'm using the latest version (to date) of pywinauto; and also using PyInspect (uia) to identify controls.

I'm automating controls on an application, and part of the process is to check a few boxes on a window that pops up after triggering the window to appear from a menu selection (like Edit->Settings).

The problem is, pywinauto doesn't seem to be able to detect the new window. I see successfully opens; and can see the window and elements as a sub (child?) window of the application in PyInspect.

I've tried wait methods, thinking the automation is occurring too fast- but to no avail. something like:

`mysettings = app['app-name'].child_window(title_re="my target settings window", class_name="#32770").wait('exists', timeout=10)`

this will just timeout. And if I print control identifiers, "my target settings window" is never included.

`app['app-name'].print_control_identifiers()`

I also tried set_focus on top_window.. that didn't work either. My conclusion is that pywinauto is having trouble detect that it is there. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue of pywinauto detecting the child window, and the issue that immediately followed: *accessing* the child window.

First, I was able to get pywinauto to detect the new window by defining backend='uia' in the application definition, like this:

`app = application.Application(backend='uia')`

I previously just had:

`app = application.Application()`

My next issue was accessing elements on the child window. I could not access the window directly, as I may have anticipated:

`app['my app']['child window']['textbox'].set_edit_text("hello world")`

Instead, this code worked:

`app['my app'].child_window(title='child window name').Edit1.set_edit_text("hello world")`

While I have resolved my issue, I have noticed that after defining backend='uia', the process now executes much slower than before. If anyone who stumbles across this has any feedback in that regard (or optimizing my efforts above), please contribute.

Thanks

Comment: Glad you could resolve it. You can mark your own answer as accepted (gray check box at left side of the answer should work for you). Regarding performance tricks for "uia" you can find something in https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/256 (need to collect all recipes into one document in the future).