# Pywinauto Doesn't Detect New Window Follow Up Question

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

Referring to answer for this question [pywinauto does not detect child window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69215801/pywinauto-does-not-detect-child-window)

I have a similar issue where I click "New" button and a window appears to key in inputs.
My problem is this new window is not listed in the print_control_identifiers(). Below is my entire code so far right up to the new window pop up

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re="SpectrumPro.*", timeout=20)
dlg = app.window(title_re="SpectrumPro.*")
app.dlg.Edit2.type_keys("XXXXXXX")
app.dlg.Edit.type_keys("YYYYYY")
app.dlg.Login.click()
app.dlg.wait("exists enabled visible ready")
app.dlg.New.click()
```

After the last line, now I have to get the new child window that had just popped up.
Below is attempt#1 and its error

```
newDLG = app.window(title="SHOP ORDER Configuration")
dlg.newDLG.print_control_identifiers()\
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title_re': 'SpectrumPro.*', 'backend': 'uia', 'process': 12244}
```

Below is attempt#2 and its error

```
newDLG = dlg.window(title="SHOP ORDER Configuration")
app.dlg.newDLG.print_control_identifiers()
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'newDLG' in 'dict_keys(['Button', 'SpectrumPro WEBButton', 'SpectrumPro WEB',.......])
```

Attempt#3 is when I tried solution from the reference stack overflow question but same issue

```
newDLG = app.dlg.child_window(title="SHOP ORDER Configuration")
app.dlg.newDLG.print_control_identifiers()
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'newDLG' in 'dict_keys(['Button', 'SpectrumPro WEBButton', 'SpectrumPro WEB',....])
```

When I use Inspect.exe, there are details of the new window buttons, text input, etc. But they don't exist in the Inspect.exe tree. So I dont know who is the parent of this new window.
Does anyone know how do I connect to this new window that popped up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in case anyone got the same issue

I had to connect the new window using a new application().connect because only this new form window is using win32 backend.

```
newApp = Application(backend="win32").connect(title_re="SHOP ORDER.*")
```

After that I was still unable to find the window using  method below

```
newDLG = app.window(title_re="SHOP ORDER Configuration")
```

I had to use magic attribute names to get the window

```
newApp.SHOPORDERConfiguration.print_control_identifiers()
```

Comment: Glad to hear. Do you experience slower execution with uia backend?

Comment: I did not notice any difference. The tasks were not repetitive enough to have a meaningful difference between uia & win32